# How to get property names from super class in sub class python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, inheritance

I have a class like below

```
class Paginator(object):
    @cached_property
    def count(self):
        some_implementation

class CachingPaginator(Paginator):
    def _get_count(self):
        if self._count is None:
            try:
                key = "admin:{0}:count".format(hash(self.object_list.query.__str__()))
                self._count = cache.get(key, -1)
                if self._count == -1:
                    self._count = self.count # Here, I want to get count property in the super-class, this is giving me -1 which is wrong
                    cache.set(key, self._count, 3600)
            except:
                self._count = len(self.object_list)
    count = property(_get_count)
```

As indicated in the comment above, `self._count = <expression>` should get the count property in super-class. If it is method we can call it like this `super(CachingPaginator,self).count()` AFAIK. I have referred many questions in SO, but none of it helped me. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: And have you tried `super(CachingPaginator,self).count`?

Comment: Or, if you are on python 3: `super().count`

Comment: @TheBrewmaster I am on python 2.7 mate...

Comment: @lokesh1729 My heart goes out to you then ;-)

Comment: @lokesh1729 that it'd be a good idea to add the python2.7 tag to your question and any other constraints there may be in an [edit]

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added...

Comment: @NilsWerner It worked...I tried reverse earlier... my bad...

Comment: Guys please don't downvote the question

Answer (score 0):

properties are just class attributes. To get a parent's class attribute, you use either direct lookup on the parent class (`Paginator.count`) or a `super()` call. Now in this case if you use direct lookup on the parent class, you'll have to invoke the descriptor protocol manually, which is a bit verbose, so using `super()` is the simplest solution:

```
class Paginator(object):
    @property
    def count(self):
        print "in Paginator.count"
        return 42

class CachingPaginator(Paginator):
    def __init__(self):
        self._count = None

    def _get_count(self):
        if self._count is None:
            self._count = super(CachingPaginator, self).count 
        # Here, I want to get count property in the super-class, this is giving me -1 which is wrong
        return self._count
    count = property(_get_count)
```

If you want a direct parent class lookup, replace:

```
self._count = super(CachingPaginator, self).count
```

with

```
self._count = Paginator.count.__get__(self, type(self))
```